# Wix: The service cannot be started during installation

Tags: service, installation, wix, clickonce

I'm having a problem with Wix Service as the service cannot be started during install progress. It throws the error:

```
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

I've tried with both `[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM]` and `[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSERVICE]` but no one of them work.

But there is weird here as I have an installer which using ClickOne, it includes the same service component as the one I have been using in Wix. The ClickOne installs service just fine (using InstallUtil.exe), so it proves the account has right to start a service.

Then, I uninstall the software (installed by ClickOne), and running the Wix installer again, the service starts well now. I don't know the reason why?

I'd like to put some flows for more clearly:

1- On a fresh machine

2- Running Wix software installer --> the service cannot be started and throwing error message --> Cancel install

3- Running ClickOne software installer --> service starts well --> Uninstalling software

4- Running Wix software installer --> service starts well

Also note that, I've tried 2 times on 2 fresh machines but it's the same. Anyone can shed some light on this weird behavior? Or anything I should verify against?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you try using installutil.exe in WiX as well?

Comment: When the service fails to start have you checked the executable's dependencies. Are you installing files to the GAC using the Windows Installer tables. In this case your dependencies won't be available when the installer runs the StartServices action. ClickOnce hasn't got this limitation, but if ClickOnce installs to the GAC then it would explain why the service works subsequently. CheckAsm.exe is pretty good for evaluating dependencies.

Comment: @jcha Check Windows logs for errors, you can find the reason why your service does not start. The most probable reason is because of missing dependencies (which ClickOnce installs by chance).

Comment: @Cosmin Pirvu: I've been trying with both InstallUtil.exe in Wix (custom action) and Wix extension utility but none of them can make the service starting.

Comment: @Stephen Connolly: As checked with CheckAsm.exe, service has no dependencies on any custom GAC assemblies. Assuming if service is depending on something, why I still can't start it manually once installation completed?

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov: The log file throws `The [Service Name] service failed to start due to the following error: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`.

Comment: so when you get that message, are you able to open the Service Control Manager UI and confirm that the service is indeed installed correctly? Appropriate usernames and passwords, correct path to the executable and arguments? It's possible that the service just isn't getting installed properly. What do you have in the ServiceInstall table? You might also try using SysInternals Processmonitor to trace what is going on during startup, assuming your service even gets as far as the initial Run() function.

Comment: Are there any events with *Side by Side* source in the log? Can you start the service executable manually, in console?

Comment: Many thanks for your comment/suggestion. Finally, I've figured out the issue. Because the service was implemented as File Watcher, it will look into a required folder to perform operations. Unfortunately, the folder has not been created during Wix installer (my silly missing). It also explains why the service starts well once ClickOne installed/removed as ClickOne created the folder already.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Stephen Connolly, @Alexey Ivanov, @Cosmin Pirvu for your comments.

I'd like to add your comments above as the answer.

1. Using [CheckAsm](http://checkasm.booring.net/), a great tool to verify the assembly dependencies
2. Looking at the log information in Event Viewer for anything could stop the service starting (i.e. timeout, services dependency ...)
3. Verifying all stuffs would be needed for service operations. They should be available once installation completed (i.e. configuration, registry, working folder ...)
4. If the installer is installing files to the GAC using the Windows Installer tables, the dependencies won't be available when the installer runs the StartServices action